# Is it possible to detect whether an object has a certain operator?

Tags: dart

I have a class that can be used for holding data, and can also help in calculating a certain value on the data.

I have some named constructors for `min` and `max`, and I was trying to add a named constructor for `sum`, but the issue that I'm running into is confirming whether or not the generic type will actually implement the `T operator +(T other)` method.

Is this something that could be handled by a `typdef`? Or is there another way? Does there need to be a `Summable<T>` interface?

Thanks in advance for the help :)

---

***Edit***
To be clear, this is a segment tree. The default constructor accepts a combiner function, typedef'd as `typedef Combiner<T> = T Function(T a, T b);`

The *named constructors*, such as `SegmentTree.min` allow for an optional Comparator (in case the objects aren't naturally Comparable to one another) and sets the `combiner = (a, b) => (comparator(a, b) <= 0) ? a : b;`

The issue I have run into as stated above is that I'm struggling to find a solution for a `SegmentTree.sum` constructor that uses the `+` operator.

Comment: No, a `typedef` won't help you.  Yes, a `Summable` interface would help.  Alternatively you could have [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) by using `dynamic` types and catching `NoSuchMethodError`, although that would be less performant, and [catching `Error`s is frowned upon](https://dart.dev/effective-dart/usage#dont-explicitly-catch-error-or-types-that-implement-it).